# Python 3.4.2 IDLE: Error when defining 'denaryInput'

Tags: python-3.x

**I am just new really to programming and for homework we had to make a denary to binary converter for homework, using a number inputed by the user. When I run this code I get the following error:**

```
    if denaryInput < 0:
NameError: name 'denaryInput' is not defined
```

**I am unsure what I am doing wrong and any answers greatly appreciated.**

**Code used:**

```
"""We are asking the user for a number"""

def getNumber():
    denaryInput = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 255: "))

"""We are validating the number"""

def validateNumber():
    if denaryInput < 0:
        print("Error: Number is too small, try again!" + " \n")
        return False
    elif denaryInput > 255:
        print("Error: Number is too big, please try again!" + " \n")
        return False
    else:
        return True

def binaryNumber():
    result = []
    for number in range(8):
        bit = denaryInput % 2
        result.append(bit)
        denaryInput = denaryInput // 2
    result.reverse()
    str1 = "".join(str(x)for x in result)
    print (str1 + " \n")    

"""Now telling the computer to run the code above and in what order of operations"""

def mainProgram():
    answer = getNumber()
    validNum = validateNumber()
    Binary = binaryNumber()
    print("The binary equlivent for that number is " + Binary + " \n")

mainProgram()
```

Comment: That variably only exists in the local scope of getNumber function

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have gotten it working now

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the denaryInput from the getnumber function as part of a call. The validatenumber function needs a value passed into it to actually be validated. These should be different names in each function.
E.g.:

```
def validateNumber(numIn):
    if numIn < 0
```

Also, you should validate the number from the getnumber function

```
denaryInput = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 255: "))
if validateNumber(denaryInput): #returns true if number valid
    Return denaryInput
```

Finally, binary is a keyword and should NOT appear in your main function.